# Is there a way to place downloads in a folder to be deleted when disk cleanup runs?

Tags: windows, download

If a download is sent to the temporary folder in Windows will disk cleanup or Ccleaner delete it when they are run?

I would like to delete downloads instead of having them stored in the download folder which takes up space.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to add *any* folder to CCleaner. From the *Options* menu select *Include*, and use the *Add* button to include the file location and file types you want automatically deleted:
[image]

You can also explicitly *Exclude* certain types from that process.

Note, however, if a file is locked by an application (e.g. you have a download open in 7-Zip), it will not be deleted during the process.